# Using a rotation vector in Android

Tags: java, android

Hey,
For an application I'm writing, I need the sort of thing [Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) offers. However, I assume it is from an old version of Android, as I cannot use this variable in my applications (I get a compilation error). I thought about using the gyroscope instead, but I'm not sure if it's equivalent, if it does - how does one get the vector, and another problem: I want to test it on my G1, and it force closes, even though as far as I understood the G1 does have some sort of a gyroscope.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "However, I assume it is from an old version of Android" - Well if you look at the docs further, you'll find it's from API Level 9 (v2.3+). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR What API Level are you building for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're correct, I didn't notice it. As I said, I'm programming for G1, so it's API Level 4 (or 5?). What can I do, then, to use something similar in API Level 4?

Answer (score 0):

G1 does not have a gyroscope.
Currently, only a few devices include gyroscope sensor.
You can have a look at this list of [devices with gyroscope sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347143/which-android-phones-out-there-do-have-a-gyroscope/8379343#8379343).

Comment: My HTC Wildfire S is not on that list, and does not have a Gyroscope Sensor, but it does have a Rotation Vector Sensor.

Comment: So, the rotation vector is calculated taking into account just the magnetic sensor and the acceleration sensor.